# How to compare two row from two different table

Tags: sql-server

i have two table with identical structure but data could be different. so i like a way to compare data between two row and display the difference in a specific way

### for say this is my sample data

```
field name                OLD VALUE      NEW VALUE

------------             ----------      ---------

Name                       Ram           sam

age                        31            56

salary                     12000         26100
```

so guide me how to write the script in sql server which will show the diff above way after comparing two row. thanks

Comment: is there a common ID?

Comment: I think i got exactly what you want. Check the first query of my post along with my fiddle demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **[unpivot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)** on both tables and a `full outer join` on the results. would be one way and i believe this is exactly what you want:

```
;WITH Table1CTE AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT ID,
               CONVERT(VARCHAR,Name) AS Name,
               CONVERT(VARCHAR,Age) AS Age,
               CONVERT(VARCHAR,Salary) AS Salary
        FROM   Table1 
    ) P
    UNPIVOT
   (
       Value For Field IN
      (Name,Age,Salary)
   ) AS T
), Table2CTE AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT ID,
               CONVERT(VARCHAR,Name) AS Name,
               CONVERT(VARCHAR,Age) AS Age,
               CONVERT(VARCHAR,Salary) AS Salary
        FROM   Table2 
    ) P
    UNPIVOT
    (
        Value For Field IN
        (Name,Age,Salary)
    ) AS T
)
SELECT COALESCE(OLD.ID,NEW.ID) AS ID,
       COALESCE(OLD.Field,NEW.Field) AS Field,
       OLD.Value AS OldValue,
       NEW.Value AS NewValue
FROM   Table1CTE OLD
       FULL OUTER JOIN Table2CTE NEW
       ON OLD.Id = NEW.Id
           AND OLD.Field = NEW.Field
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78323/18)**

One other way would be multiple unions:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Old.Id,New.Id) AS ID,
       'Name' AS 'Field',
       Old.Name AS 'Old Value',
       New.Name AS 'New Value'
FROM   Table1 Old
       FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 New
           ON Old.Id = New.Id
UNION ALL
SELECT COALESCE(Old.Id,New.Id) AS ID,
       'Age' AS 'Field',
       Old.Age AS 'Old Value',
       New.Age AS 'New Value'
FROM   Table1 Old
       FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 New
           ON Old.Id = New.Id
UNION ALL
SELECT COALESCE(Old.Id,New.Id) AS ID,
       'salary' AS 'Field',
       Old.Salary AS 'Old Value',
       New.Salary AS 'New Value'
FROM   Table1 Old
       FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 New
           ON Old.Id = New.Id
```

Another way would be to have all differences of each id in a single row:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Old.Id,New.Id) AS ID,
       Old.Name AS 'OldName',
       New.Name AS 'NewName',
       Old.Age AS 'OldAge',
       New.Age AS 'NewAge',
       Old.Salary AS 'OldSalary',
       New.Salary AS 'NewSalary'
FROM   Table1 Old
       FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 New
           ON Old.Id = New.Id
```

Comment: Because i have an id (2) on Table 1 that does not exist in Table 2 and an id (3) on table 2 that does not exist on Table 1. I did not know if in your scenario there would be cases that there exist an id in one table but not in the other. This ensures that you get all ids no matter if they have matches on both tables.

Comment: i have one request. please remove id from the output of the result and i guess then no null value will show. update fiddler & answer here too. thanks

Comment: If you do not want the `null`s to display then change the `FULL OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` and you are good to go. But this way you will not know if there is an id that exists on only one of the tables. Removing the `id` from the result will not make any difference at all (apart from not showing the id), so if you do not need it just comment it out. The reason i am displaying it is that you would want somehow to know where are the differences.

Comment: i comment the id then got query compilation error. can u comment it in sql fiddler. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #aaa 
(
    id INT,
    NAME NVARCHAR(10)
)
CREATE TABLE #bbb
(
    id INT,
    NAME NVARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO #aaa( id, NAME )
VALUES  ( 1, N'aaa'), (2, N'bbb')  

INSERT INTO #bbb( id, NAME )
VALUES  ( 1, N'ccc'), (2, N'bbb')


(
    SELECT *
    FROM #aaa
    EXCEPT
    SELECT *
    FROM #bbb            
)
UNION ALL              
(
    SELECT *
    FROM #bbb
    EXCEPT
    SELECT *
    FROM #aaa     
)
```

If you don't have any relations between this two tables - it's unreal to find "old" and "new" values.